# Getting value of select option php

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, post

I want to get a value of select option php on the same page. I brought selection list from database and listed them on the select. But even though I choose something on the list, it's not posted. Is there any problem in the code below? Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="ibox-content m-b-sm border-bottom">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="status">Search by category</label>
                    <form action="" method="POST" >
                    <select name="category" class="form-control">
                        <option value="" selected>All</option>
                <?php
                    while($category = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        // output data from each row
                        echo "<option value=\"{$category['categoryID']}\">{$category['name']}</option>";
                    }
                ?>
                    </select>
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
                        </input>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo "Got it!";
        echo $_POST['category'];
    }?>
```

Comment: I can't spot anything, but does it echo out "Got it!" after you submit the form?

Comment: Is your select menu being created correctly before you make a selection? You're seeing the values you expect in it? I tested your code, just changing to my own array instead of your "while" with your database content and your code is working correctly for me.

Comment: @Qirel No I get nothing...

Comment: could you provide sample of data you write it in list? "I mean the data comes from DB"

Comment: @Johnnie That's really weird, because that code works perfectly on my end, tested and tried.

Comment: @Developer H  1 Electronics
11 Household appliances
21 Clothes
31 Shoes

Comment: I think it's related to server or URL.

Comment: I test your code on http://phpfiddle.org/ and it works find.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a name for the option:

```
<option name='category' value=\"{$category['categoryID']}\"...
```

And try adding `action='#'`, and then it works:

```
array (size=2)
  'category' => string '1' (length=1)
  'submit' => string 'Search' (length=6)

Got it!1
```

And take care, in your code the option for 'all' has no value, and won't be displayed.

Comment: `<option>`-tags don't have a name, the `<select>` does - which OP already has specified. And the value is the one being submitted, not what's being displayed.

Answer (score -1):

You have:

```
<?php
 while($category = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
     // output data from each row
     echo "<option value=\"{$category['categoryID']}\">{$category['name']}</option>";
 }
?>
```

An array key -> inside a template var -> inside an option -> in a double-quoted string (which will parse vars), -> inside a while loop (which may or may not be running).  That level of nested complexity will certainly decrease your time-to-debug and simplicity-to-debug.

I would first ignore the html entirely and:

```
$category = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)
var_dump($category, $category['categoryID'], $category['name']);
```

in naked php, to make sure that you have exactly what you need before you put anything into the html.

Also, form action='' sometimes causes problems, so make that and everything else you can explicit and fixed just while debugging.

I have to say that you're making things harder for yourself by not using a template engine, especially at the early stages.  Your html+php is low-readability, and that decreases the ease of debugging.  Use a clean template and it'll be easier to debug echoing issues, and as a side benefit you'll get easy escaping.